# countable and uncountable word "noise" - a sound

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

According to the Oxford dictionary, the word *[noise](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/noise)* can be considered countable or non-countable when it means "**a sound, especially when it is loud, unpleasant or disturbing**". But it doesn't provide any more insights as to when it is countable or non-countable. Although there are some example sentences, it is very difficult to figure it out from them.

So I'm not sure whether *noise* is in its correct form in the sentences below.

> The wooden queen-size bed always produces **noise** when we lie down on it. We had not noticed this issue until we moved in. Despite I am very careful when I turn my body from one side to another, it is still rather noisy and my wife always complains of the annoying **noises**.

It's quite difficult to distinguish it from its meaning as it is the same. What is the insight?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense for the dictionary to say a word is countable and uncountable without saying in which context is uncountable. If _noises_ is used as Jim says, then I would not consider _noise_ uncountable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bunch of individual *noises* (a cow mooing, a dog barking, a bird singing) when occurring at the same time, can be considered collectively to be just *noise*.

I would only talk about *noises* when you mean to make a distinction between them either in time or by source.

> You were making a lot of noises in your sleep last night.

This means at multiple times during the night you made some noise.

> You were making a lot of noise in your sleep last night.

This would more likely be interpreted as you making noise in a more continuous way throughout the night.

> I can't think with all this noise.

Here *noise* means the sum of all noises being heard. (The lawnmower, the traffic, the dog, the television, the neighbors, etc.)

I would rewrite your sentences:

> The queen-size wooden bed always *makes* noise when we lie down on it. We had not noticed this issue until we moved in. Even when I am very careful as I turn over in bed, the noise still annoys my wife and she always complains about it.

Comment: Thanks. Is it uncountable in the example "a lot of noise" or the last one(sum)?

Comment: Yes, I'd call that a non-count noun;  It's behaves like "a lot of milk" or "a lot of money"